# STL Map as a default argument

Tags: c++, stl

How to pass stl map as a default argument?

Comment: Can you give us a little more detail on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: As a default parameter to what? Please when asking describe the problem in as much detail as possible.

Comment: As default parameter to any of the methods.

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong on this question. It's pretty clear what is he asking. For me is this question understandable (+1).

Answer (score 7):

```
typedef std::map<int,int> MyMap;

void myFunction (int arg1, int arg2, MyMap arg3=MyMap());
```

EDIT: forgot the argument name, sorry.

Comment: Huh? No name, just type? It's allowed, when there's no value, but in this case?

Comment: @Armen - nice, that's interesting. +1 now.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the argument name.  It's corrected now.

Comment: @Patrick: the argument name wasn't necessary. You could provide it the function definition

Comment: @Armen, I know the argument name isn't strictly needed, but it helps in reading the function prototype.  A proptotype like "print(int width, int height, int dpi)" says more than "print(int,int,int)".

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
void CObject::someMethod(std::map<std::string, int> someMapContainer)
```

But honestly I dont understand fully your question.

Comment: Hey actually I have a class. And it has a method called xyz(). I am calling this method twice from other method which is not member of the class to which xyz() belongs. And I want to have a map which will contain common data between both the calls to xyz(). I have some constraints like I can't use global variable or static variable.